# Why are Amazon OpsWorks operations so slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opsworks

I'm starting to examine Amazon OpsWorks and created a stack with a database layer and 2 custom layers.
I put my cookbooks on a private git repository.
I'm wondering why machines used in my scenario are **so damn slow** !?
When booting the machines the first time it took around 15-30min until they are ready and even why I just start the task "update custom cookbooks" it takes 4(!!) minutes to fetch them from github.
I already red about creating custom AMIs for reducing boot time but then I have to remove the `opsworks-agent`.
Would I still be able to use the OpsWorks interface wehen removing the agent?

Do I miss something or is the process so slow for everyone? I'm using `m1.small` intances for testing purpose.

Comment: It's very slow for me too, I've asked a similar question on the AWS forums and got no response :( You can look through the logs for a run and see the breakdown by time, but there's nothing obvious consuming more time than it should. Otherwise OpsWorks is great!

Comment: @thexacre yeah totally agree :/

Comment: Yea it is extremely slow & very irritating at times.

Comment: Probably depends on your target OS that you're trying to setup. I imagine a Windows-based system would take far longer to setup than something from the Linux realm.

Answer (score 1):

Because ruby is compiled during the `running_setup` to run the `opsworks-agent` if you are using an O.S. without ruby `2.0.0` by default. (i.e. the Amazon Linux AMI has ruby 2.0.0 built in, so is faster than ubuntu for provision).

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately quite standard, even in 2022, for anything cloud related.

Whenever you ask a "cloud" to create and start something, it will have to actually provision it and get it runnning; which means telling *a lot* of different systems to create and start that thing you asked for.

"Asynchronous", also known as "you ask it to do something, and it will eventually do it whenever it wants".